# Bash tab completion script

Tags: auto-completion

I have pass installed and working. However, I cannot get the tab completion to work. I have placed the tab completion script in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`. The script is called `password-store`. When I run

```
source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/password-store
```

the tab completion work in my current terminal session. However, upon rebooting or closing that terminal session I lose the tab completion for pass. How do I make this persistent? I've read that Ubuntu handles these dynamically, but I'm not sure how to make this work.  I'm running Lubuntu 14.04.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line

```
source /path/to/your/tab/completion/script
```

to the file `~/.bash_completion` which is automatically sourced by `~/.bashrc`, making it persistent.

Note that you don't need to put the actual script in a specific location, you can choose the path that's most convenient to you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/password-store` to your `~/.bashrc` and then source the latter by running `source ~/.bashrc`.